# Is it possible to override table name in Doctrine Entities?

Tags: php, doctrine, mappedsuperclass

I'm using Doctrine ORM.
When trying to get data from database I get this error:
`Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'db.GenericMeasurements' doesn't exist` 
Code that generates error:

```
$sensor = $entityManager->getRepository('EspRemoteServer\Entity\GenericSensor')->getSensor(1);
    foreach ($sensor as $s)
    {
        $measurement = $s->getMeasurements();
        $values = $measurement->getValues();
    }
```

It enters getValues() and generates error when trying execute sql.
I tried to do something with AssociationOverride, but it seems that I cannot override table name.
**GenericMeasurements.php**

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\MappedSuperclass
 */
abstract class GenericMeasurements
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="time", type="datetime", nullable=false)
     */
    private $time;

    /**
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="GenericSensor", inversedBy="measurements")
    * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="sensor_id", referencedColumnName="id")
    */
    private $sensor;

    function __construct()
    {
    }

    //getters and setters
}
```

**DS18B20Measurements.php**

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="ds18b20_sensor")
*/
class DS18B20Measurements extends GenericMeasurements
{
    use TemperatureTrait;

    function __construct()
    {
    }
}
```

**GenericSensor.php**

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="EspRemoteServer\Entity\Repository\GenericSensorRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="sensors")
 */
class GenericSensor
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /** 
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", nullable=false)
     */
    private $name;
    
    /** 
     * @ORM\Column(name="token", type="string", nullable=false)
     */
    private $token;
    
    /** 
    * @ORM\Column(name="description", type="text")
    */
    private $description;
    
    /** 
    * @ORM\Column(name="location", type="string", nullable=false)
    */
    private $location;

    /**
    * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="GenericMeasurements", mappedBy="sensor")
    **/
    private $measurements;


    function __construct($name = '', $token = '', $description = '', $location = '')
    {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->token = $token;
        $this->description = $description;
        $this->location = $location;
        $this->measurements = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    //getters and setters
}
```

Comment: I want to get data from 'ds18b20_sensor' table and some more, because i have single table with measurements for every sensors.

Comment: What is inside of `getSensor` method?

Comment: it's getter for sensor property. Returns entity GenericSensor.